# nginx: "X" directive is not allowed here in default virtual host config

Tags: nginx

I have searched around for a while on this error, and I can't pick up anything offensive in my config files. When running a config test, it gives me the error above (for any line added to the virtual host default config), which has me stumped since the server was running fine. I've included the files below:

sites-available/default:

```
worker_processes 1;

user www-data www-data;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/nginx.error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;
    sendfile on;

upstream app_server {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    # For a TCP configuration:
    # server 192.168.0.7:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    # If no Host match, close the connection to prevent Host spoofing
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name serverName;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    #root /home/ubuntu/appName/static;
location /static {
        #root /home/ubuntu/appName/;
        alias /home/ubuntu/appName/static/;
}

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
         try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /path/to/app/current/public;
    }
}
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections 768;
   # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Can anyone pick up what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including main level configuration items in the site level configuration.

This is what you can include in the `sites-enabled` file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    # For a TCP configuration:
    # server 192.168.0.7:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    # If no Host match, close the connection to prevent Host spoofing
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name serverName;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    #root /home/ubuntu/appName/static;

    location /static {
        #root /home/ubuntu/appName/;
        alias /home/ubuntu/appName/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
         try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://example.com;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /path/to/app/current/public;
    }
}
```